# Clean install of Fedora17 and keeping current home directory

Tags: linux, installation, fedora

```
HP Mini 210
Fedora 16
```

Hello,

I have downloaded the recent F17 Beta live CD and would like to install it.

Normally, when I install I always select the following custom partitions:

```
/boot
/swap
/root
/home
```

I am just wondering is it possible to install Fedora17 and keep my existing partitions so my home directory will not be formatted?

I would like to format the following partitions boot, swap, and root. As I don't want to leave any unwanted files that could impact F17.

Basically, I want to do a clean install but keep my exiting home partition.

Many thanks for any suggestions,

Comment: The key thing is to **not reformat your `/home` partition** during the install process.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe it's possible to do so with the live media. You will need either the full DVD or the network install image; these will allow you to select in Anaconda (the installer) which partitions will be formatted.